Uniqueness of homomorphism that extends $\phi$ to $F[\alpha]$
I'm trying to fresh up my notes from abstract algebra classes and I've came across such an exercise that I have questions about:
let $\phi: F \to L$ be field homomorphism, $\alpha$ is algebraic over $F$, $\beta \in L$ is a root of $\phi(m_{\alpha})$. Then there is unique homomorphism $\psi$ that extends $\phi$ to $F[\alpha]$ and $\psi(\alpha) = \beta$
The problem is that I do not understand how to construct such homomorphism and the way we've proved it.
I have this in our class notes:
Since $\alpha$ is algebraic over $$, $_{\alpha, F} = \sum_{i=0}^{n}{a_i\alpha^i} = 0$. Then $\phi(_{\alpha, F}) = \sum_{i=0}^{n}{\psi(a_i)\psi(\alpha)^i} = \sum_{i=0}^{n}{\phi(a_i)\beta^i} = 0$. Existance is obvious. (now I don't understand what's going on here: why is it obvious and what's the exact formula for $\psi$?).
Let's prove uniqueness: suppose that $\phi$ (I guess it's naming problem that it has the same letter) satisfies our conditions then $\sum_{i=0}^{n}{\phi(a_i)\beta^i} = 0$ (why?). Hence we got two polynomials of minimal degree which generate Ideal $I = \{f(x) \in F'(\beta)[x] | f(\beta) = 0\}$. This ideal is prime (it's clear to me) then $(\psi(m_{\alpha, F})) \sim (\phi(m_{\alpha, F}))$ and somehow they obtained contradiction.
I don't understand how $\psi$ is constructed and do not understand the part with uniqueness at all... I've rewritten this notes in order to provide more context for my question.

Let's see the existence first. Since $\phi$ is defined on $F$, and $F[\alpha]$ is obtained by just adding $\alpha$ and letting the field operations do the rest, it's clear that it suffices to specify which value $\alpha$ should have under the extension $\psi$ (not that this could suffice as an argument for uniqueness). It is also clear that this value, whatever it is, has to be a root of $\phi(m_{\alpha})$. But the question remains: can we just pick any such root ? How can we be sure that none of them would induce some conflict with the original $\phi$ ?
The trick is to use the isomorphism $F[X]/(m_{\alpha}) \cong F[\alpha]$, which sends $X$ to $\alpha$. To see that this is an isomorphism, notice that $F[X] \rightarrow F[\alpha]$ is surjective, and has kernel $(m_{\alpha})$. Now, in order to construct a well-defined map $F[X]/(m_{\alpha}) \rightarrow L$, all we have to do is define $F[X] \rightarrow L$, and make sure $(m_{\alpha})$ is in the kernel, so we can factor it through the quotient, which is non other than $F[\alpha]$, as we just argued.
But defining some map $F[X] \rightarrow L$ which extends $\phi$ is very easy: we can pick the image of $X$ to be whatever we want in $L$ (there is no risk of conflict) ! AND if the image we pick happens to be a root $\beta$ of $\phi(m_{\alpha})$, we see that $(m_{\alpha})$ is in the kernel, so the map factors through some map $\psi:F[\alpha] \rightarrow L$, which extends $\phi$ and maps $\alpha$ to $\beta$.
If you need more convincing arguments for uniqueness than the "$\psi$ is determined by its values on $F$ and on $\alpha$" I stated above, you could also observe that $F[\alpha]$ is an $F$-vector space with $(1,\alpha, \alpha^2,...,\alpha^{d-1})$ as a basis. As $L$ is also an $F$-vector space (via the original $\phi$), any extension $\psi$ of $\phi$ is a morphism of $F$-vector spaces. It is therefore uniquely specified by the image of the above basis. Now, once $\beta = \psi(\alpha)$ is fixed, this imposes $\psi(\alpha^i) = \beta^i$ (because $\psi$ is a field homomorphism), hence $\psi$ is completely determined on the basis just by choosing the root $\beta$.

thanks, it's better now. Could you please provide the exact formula of your homomorphisms? what do you mean by "$F[x] \to F[\alpha]$", is it $g(x) = g(\alpha)$? And what do you mean by  "we can pick the image of X
to be whatever we want in L"? I'd be much clearer if you could give exact mapping tule. thanks a lot!

is it true that in the notes that I provided "we can pick the image of X to be whatever we want in L" is decided to just pick the image given by $\phi$?

well, I have problems in understanding the third paragraph of yours. what do you mean by "if the image happens to be a root of ...", shouldn't it be true without if condition? I mean, we need to construct such mapping that it is true, and show it's exact mapping rule

Yes, the morphism $F[X] \rightarrow F[\alpha]$ is defined as the unique ring morphism which is the identity on $F$ and which sends $X$ to $\alpha$. So If you have $g \in F[X]$, it is mapped to $g(\alpha)$.

In general, if $A$ and $R$ are two rings, specifying a ring map $f:A[X] \rightarrow S$ is equivalent to specifying a ring map $g:A \rightarrow S$ (the restriction of $f$ to $A$) together with an element $s$ (which corresponds to $f(X)$). As the indeterminate satisfies no relation, there is no constraint on what its image can be. This is the universal property of polynomial rings, which you can find somewhere on this page.

When I wrote "if the image happens to be a root of ...", I was talking about the general case of a morphism $F[X] \rightarrow L$ if there was no mention of $\beta$. Of course, in our setting, we want the image to be $\beta$, so the condition will be satisfied.
